Spaceship on an exploratory mission encounters enemy fleet
I've been remembering parts of an older scifi movie for awhile now but can't remember the name or find it. It's been driving me crazy today. It's an older movie, I remember it from TV and that was many years ago.
The movie is about a spaceship that's on some kind of exploration and they encounter an enemy fleet (might have been a longstanding enemy race that went disappeared off the scene for awhile). After or during the encounter their communications system/antenna/array gets damaged from a collision with an asteroid. The enemy fleet is heading for a spacegate/warpgate that ships use to jump galaxies (built by the humans). Because the human's access to the gate is impossible and their communication is out, they have to find another way of contacting the human space fleet. One of the people on the crew is descended from a group of people who can make spacejumps by heart/instinct without the calculations of the spacegate (might have been nomads/smugglers idk). Outside of this group everyone relies on the gates because the jumps are either to hard to make or to calculate. The man is reluctant at first to make the jump.

I am pretty sure you're describing Wing Commander (1999).  The people who could make space jumps by heart/instinct are called "Pilgrims".  Their descendants are regarded with suspicion because "They don't think like we do."

This is indeed the movie I was looking for. Thank you so much. ^^
